# jQuery load() issue added breaks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm having a problem with my .load function. I'm having an issue when the data has loaded it putting  line breaks on the top and bottom of the text area. I checked the database to see if the issue was coming from there but it's not. So can anyone help me please. Thank you..

http://gyazo.com/a0562c067824c10b82aae17c2e918353

HTML Code

```
<div class="col-md-4">Match ID</div>
<div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="match_id" id="match_id" value="<?if(isset($_POST['match_id']))  echo $_POST['match_id']?>" /></div>

<div class="col-md-4">Ticket Category</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <select class='form-control' name="ticket_category" id="ticket_category">
        <option value="-1">Select One..</option>
        <?php
        foreach ($ticket->getStaffcategories() as $key => $value){
            echo "<option value=\"$value[id]\">$value[name]</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">Body</div>
<div class="col-md-8"><textarea rows="5" id="Ticketbody" class="form-control"><?if(isset($_POST['Ticketbody'])) echo $_POST['Ticketbody']?></textarea></div>
```

PHP Code

```
$("#ticket_category").change(function(){
    var id = parseInt($('#ticket_category').val());
    if(id != -1){
        $("#Ticketbody").html('Retrieving Information...');
        $("#Ticketbody").load('../includes/function.php?function=gettickettemp',{'categorie_id':id}, 'text');
   }else{
        $("#Ticketbody").html('');
   }
});
```

function PHP Code

```
case "gettickettemp":
    if(isset($_POST["categorie_id"])){

        $categorie_id = $sql->escape_string($_POST["categorie_id"]);
        $getTemp = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM `ticket_categories` WHERE `id` = '$categorie_id'");
        $tempData = $getTemp->fetch_assoc();

        $data = str_replace('<br>', "\n", $tempData['body']);

        echo $data;
    }
    break;
```

Comment: trim it before it leaves php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was suggested in the comment by @dandavis, you should trim the string in PHP before it gets sent to your browser:

```
case "gettickettemp":
    if(isset($_POST["categorie_id"])){

        $categorie_id = $sql->escape_string($_POST["categorie_id"]);
        $getTemp = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM `ticket_categories` WHERE `id` = '$categorie_id'");
        $tempData = $getTemp->fetch_assoc();

        $data = str_replace('<br>', "\n", $tempData['body']);

        echo trim($data); // <-- remove whitespace here.
    }
    break;
```

You can check if the payload contains the whitespace by using Chrome's dev tools.  If you press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Mac) and then click on the `network` tab, new AJAX requests should show up there.  If not, then reload the page, and you should see all the requests, with new ones showing up at the bottom.

You can inspect the content that the server sent back to you by clicking on the `response` tab.

[image: screenshot]